# Delphi - remote data module list of active connections?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, datasnap

I have a Delphi-based client-server application. The server is a fairly simple application with a TRemoteDataModule. The client application connects to it via a TSocketConnection.

Everything is working fine on that front.

Is there a way to access the list of currently active connections for the TRemoteDataModule?

The reason I'm asking is because I would like to prevent users from connecting from more than one machine at a time to the same server, so I figured I would keep a list of usernames per connection and check against it whenever a new connection is attempted, or beforehand, client-side, via a a COM function. 
Or should I be using some other mechanism altogether?

As an aside, is there a way to see which threading model and instancing model were used when creating the RDM? I'm not the one who created it, and I don't know where to find that.

Cheers!

Using Delphi XE5, if that makes a difference

Comment: It would be ok if a user connects multiple time from the same machine?

Comment: @mjn: yes, that would be fine. Thanks!